# Passing an Python Class Attribute Given a String

Tags: python, class, attributes

Here is a class

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def set_value(self,"attribut_String",value):   # passing a attribute in String
        if "attribut_String" = "AAAA":
            self.cal_function("a",value) 
        else "attribut_String" = "BBBB":
            self.cal_function("b",value) 

    def cal_function(self,att,value):
        self.att = value       # process the passing string as attribute object
```

Now , i'm try to a result like this :

```
input:rlt = A(a = 1, b = 2)
input:rlt.a
output: 1
input:rlt.set_value("a",3)
input:rlt.a
output:4
```

May it seems unnecessary because I simplified the scenario . I have to code in this way

Comment: have a look at `getattr` and `setattr`

Comment: What not just use `rlt.a = 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a control flow inside your `set_value` function:

```
def set_value(self, member, value):
    if member == "a":
        self.a = value
    elif member == "b":
        self.b = value
```

If you don't mind dropping the `set_value` function, you can use the [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function:

```
setattr(myobject, "a", value)
```

or even

```
def set_value(self, member, value):
    setattr(self, member, value)
```

You can also use a dictionary:

```
def set_value(self, member, value):
    members = {
        "a" : self.a,
        "b" : self.b
    }
    members[member] = value
```

Comment: what do you do with `members` in the last step?

Comment: hi, Alestanis , that's really classic explanation . but sorry , I didn't make myself clear enough..could you pls check the updated question ?Thanks