# General setter for a class using strings

Tags: python, getter-setter

Let's say I have a class called "Employee" which was a bunch of different attributes. I can create a general getter which would basically get every attribute based on a string of its name like this but I don't know how to create a setter of the sort so I wouldn't have to do something like `employee1.age = 22` every time. And creating multiple setter for every attribute would be pretty messy.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = "Somewhere"
        self.job = None

    def getter(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name, None)

    def setter(self, name, amount):
        pass
```

Comment: Creating a general getter and setter may not be necessary. You can pass the age information on the creation of the class instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421659/passing-variables-creating-instances-self-the-mechanics-and-usage-of-classes

Comment: @L.Clarkson Didn't exactly solve the problem but thanks :thumbs-up:

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376135/passing-an-python-class-attribute-given-a-string

Comment: @L.Clarkson Yeah I think you're right. Should I close the question?

Comment: I can mark as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an Python Class Attribute Given a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376135/passing-an-python-class-attribute-given-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setattr()` and wrap it in your `setter` method like this:

```
    def setter(self, name, amount):
        return setattr(self, name, amount)
```

So you'd call it like this

```
e = Employee("Albert", 169)
e.setter("age", 16)
```

and when you check now for `e.age` you will see

```
>>> e.age
16
```

Comment: Oh shoot! That was so stupid of me lol! Didn't know setattr existed. Thank you! You're a life saver

Comment: You would probably be better off not wrapping it, however, and just using setattr() directly .. unless there are some other things you want to do with the inputs

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Yeah that does actually make sense. Thank you though! LMAO can't believe I asked that question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joe Carboni's answer, I managed to create a function I'd like to call the `ultimate_getter()`. I'll put it here for you all to use.

```
def ultimate_getter(obj, name, limit = 12):

    if name.count(".") == 0:
        return getattr(self, name, None)

    else:
        count = 0
        previous = None
        current = None
        previous = obj

        while name.count(".") > 0 and count < limit:
            index = name.find(".")
            previous = getattr(previous, name[0:index])
            name = name[index + 1:]
            count += 1

            if name.count(".") == 0:
                current = getattr(previous, name)

        return current
```

It's basically a more advanced version of `setattr()` which can loop through the text so you wouldn't have to use `setattr()` a bunch of times when wanting to use sort of a nested attribute/method.